# Footer content positioning problem with WooFoo Contact Form and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css

I am working with a to client fix a problem on a single page. On all pages, the footer content is positioned and displays properly. However, on [this page](http://www.theideapeople.com/contact_us.html), when viewed in IE7 the footer content moves up into the body area. The only difference between this page and all the other is the presence of a WooFoo contact form.

I have tried a zillion different ways to bump that content down, but it will not respond to padding or margin adjustments.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="width">
<ul class="footerNav">
  <li><a class="bFB" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Charlotte-NC/The-Idea-People/124178504825" target="_blank" title="The Idea People Charlotte web design facebook">FaceBook</a></li>
  <li><a class="bTW" href="http://twitter.com/theideapeople" target="_blank" title="The Idea People Charlotte web design twitter">Twitter</a></li>
  <li><a class="bEM" href="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=theideapeople" target="_blank" title="The Idea People Charlotte web design email">FeedBurner</a></li>
  <li><a class="bRSS" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/theideapeople" target="_blank" title="The Idea People Charlotte web design rss">RSS</a></li>
</ul>
<br class="clear" />
<ul class="termNav">
  <li><a href="terms.html">Terms of Use</a> |</li>
  <li><a href="privacy_policy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul>
<p class="copyright">&copy;2010 The Idea People. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p class="company">Charlotte, NC web design, graphic design and internet marketing</p>
<div id="address"> <strong>The Idea People</strong><br />
  4424 Taggart Creek Rd., Suite 111<br />
  Charlotte, NC 28208 </div>
<div id="phone"> <strong>T</strong> 704.398.4437<br />
  <strong>F</strong> 704.398.4438<br />
  <strong>E</strong> <a href="mailto:ideas@theideapeople.com">ideas@theideapeople.com</a> </div>
<br class="clear"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#footer      { clear: both; background: url(../images/bg_footer.png) 0 0 no-repeat; padding: 10px 0 76px; color: #ccc; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;  }
#footer .width { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; }                                                
.footerNav { width: 300px; height: 30px; font-size: 15px; position: relative; top: 5px; left: 770px; }
.footerNav li   { position:relative; float:left; margin:0; }
.footerNav li a  { color: #fff; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; text-indent: -9999px; }

.footerNav li a.bRSS { background: url(../images/icon-rss.png) 0 0 no-repeat; width: 28px; height: 28px; padding-left: 26px; }
.footerNav li a.bFB   { background: url(../images/icon-facebook.png) 0 0 no-repeat; width: 28px; height: 28px; padding-left: 26px; }
.footerNav li a.bTW  { background: url(../images/icon-twitter.png) 0 0 no-repeat; width: 28px; height: 28px; padding-left: 26px; }
.footerNav li a.bEM  { background: url(../images/icon-email.png) 0 0 no-repeat; width: 28px; height: 28px; padding-left: 26px; }
```

Any help in resolving this will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.footerNav` element is causing overflow and busting the layout.  I even get horizontal scrollbars on my machine, on all browsers.

The following CSS seems to fix it:

```
.footerNav 
{
    /* Add clear and float
    */
    clear:      left;
    float:      right;
    font-size:  15px;
    height:     30px;
    top:        5px;
    /* Delete these 3
    position:   relative;
    left:       770px;
    width:      300px;
    */
}
```

Comment: Hi Brock,

I tried the code, but it caused the icons to go way off to the right and added the horizontal scroll bar. And it threw things off in the browsers that were working.

Comment: Weird, that doesn't make sense unless, maybe, the `left` was left in.  Please post a link to the modified page.

Comment: Hi Brock,

Here you go: http://www.theideapeople.com/contact_us.html

Be sure to view it in IE7

Comment: Hi FMZ, that's the page without my CSS changes (as of a few seconds ago).  I open it in IE7 and see the problem.  I make my changes and the problem disappears.

Comment: I had it in the IE7 exceptions stylesheet. Then I moved it over to the regular stylesheet and I am back to where I started.

Comment: Oops, I was spot checking in FF, to see the final computed styles -- but that doesn't work for conditionally-included, IE styles.
Now, when I open it in IE7, I see the problem -- even with my changes.   Also killing the `position: relative;` seems to fix it.